# How do you set up a python project to be able to send to others without them having to manually copy and paste the code into an editor

Tags: python

I made a cool little project for my friend, basically a timer using tkinter, but I am confused on how to let them access this project without having vscode or pycharm. Is it possible for them to just see the Tkinter window or something like that?  Is there an application for this? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Do you want to share the source code with them (you could use git for this), or simply share a packaged application?

Comment: can you elaborate more on packaged application?

Comment: there is the executable way or the online demo method, what you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You can just built an .exe (Application) of your project. Then just share the application file and anyone can use the application through .exe. You can use pyinstaller to convert your python code to exe.

**pip install pyinstaller**

then cd to the project folder then run the following command

**pyinstaller --onefile YourFileName.py**

if you want to make exe without console showing up then use this command

**pyinstaller --onefile YourFileName.py --noconsole**

Comment: You can run python Tkinter demos online here [link](https://repl.it/languages/tkinter), so you can avoid to prepare a specific executable package for every OS. And then share it